# помогите как передать объект в ту же activity при смене ориентации?

Tags: java, android

суть приложения в том что есть 6 вопросов 2 кнопки тру фолс. 2 кнопки на след вопрос и назад. при ответе на вопрос кнопки(тру фолс) становятся недоступны. когда будут ответы на все вопросы всплывает тоаст с % правильных ответов.  в портретном все работает.  я сделал hashset в который записываю индексы массива с вопросами. и проверяю после каждого ответа есть ли пустые значения в массиве, если нет то всплывает тоаст с %. При смене ориентации кнопки снова активны. я хотел передать hashset(с именем haveAnswers) с индексами в альбомную активити, чтобы и в альбомной ориентации было известно на какие вопросы были даны ответы. Пробовал по примерам сделать это с помощью Parcelable, не получается. во всех примерах описывается передача интента в другую активити и другого класса имплементирующего Parcelable. а тут получается всё в одном классе. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать?

P.S. Далее привожу работоспособную версию кода:

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";
    private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";
    private static final String KEY_BUTTONS = "keyButtons";

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private ImageButton mPrevButton;
    private ImageButton mNextButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;
    private boolean f;
    private int correctAnswers = 0;

    private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[] {
            new Question(R.string.question_australia, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_asia, true)
    };



  private HashSet<Integer> haveAnswers = new HashSet<>(mQuestionBank.length);

    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
        }

        mQuestionTextView = findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        updateQuestion();
        mQuestionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nextUpdate();
                checkButtons();
            }
        });

        mTrueButton = findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(true);
            }
        });

        mFalseButton = findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(false);
            }
        });

        mPrevButton = findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
        mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCurrentIndex > 0) {
                    mCurrentIndex--;
                }
                checkButtons();
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });

        mNextButton = findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nextUpdate();
                checkButtons();
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTrueButton.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_BUTTONS, true));
            mFalseButton.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_BUTTONS, true));
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "on Start() called");
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        outState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_BUTTONS, mTrueButton.isEnabled());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
    }

    private void updateQuestion() {

        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }

    private void nextUpdate() {
        if (mCurrentIndex < 5) {
            mCurrentIndex++;
        }
        updateQuestion();
    }

    private void checkButtons() {
        if (!haveAnswers.contains(mCurrentIndex)) {
            mTrueButton.setEnabled(true);
            mFalseButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mTrueButton.setEnabled(false);
            mFalseButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {

        mTrueButton.setEnabled(false);
        mFalseButton.setEnabled(false);
        haveAnswers.add(mCurrentIndex);

        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();

        int messageResId = 0;

        if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
            correctAnswers++;
        } else {
            messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
        }
        //Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0 ,200);
        t.show();

        if (haveAnswers.size() == mQuestionBank.length) {
            Toast.makeText(this, String.format("You have %d%%", correctAnswers*100/mQuestionBank.length), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: так в книжке написано: Листинг 3.6. Переопределение onSaveInstanceState(…) (QuizActivity.java)
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
}

Comment: запустил в порядке указанном вами, разницы не заметил, да и в любом случае проблему это не решает.

Comment: Да, извините, проверил, действительно, вариант из книги должен работать. Уточните, что именно вызывает проблемы, пожалуйста. Работает ли у Вас вообще восстановление состояния через `bundle`?

Comment: проблема не в bundle. восстановление состояния работает для кнопок prev и next и для mCurrentIndex(текущий вопрос). я же хочу передавать haveAnswers в новосозданную активити, но с помощью onSaveInstanceState это сделать невозможно(насколько мне известно), так вот как и чем это сделать?

Comment: Так, я правильно понимаю, что у Вас для разных ориентаций - разные классы активности?

Comment: нет. активность одна. а макета 2.

Comment: но я вижу ровно один макет здесь, где же тогда вообще второй?

Comment: второй макет с тем же именем, но в в папке layout-land

Comment: ох, тогда мне надо будет освежить память(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаем из бандла

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    mTrueButton.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_BUTTONS, true));
    mFalseButton.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_BUTTONS, true));
    haveAnswers = new HashSet<Integer>(){{
        addAll(savedInstanceState.getIntegerArrayList("ANSWERS"));
    }};
}
```

Сохраняем в бандл

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    outState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
    outState.putBoolean(KEY_BUTTONS, mTrueButton.isEnabled());
    outState.putIntegerArrayList("ANSWERS", new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
        addAll(haveAnswers);
    }});
}
```

Comment: ЗАРАБОТАЛО! большое спасибо!

Comment: Рад был помочь)